# How to save user's last location in app (not geo)? React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to JS and React Native. Making a small mobile app.

I have reached  the point where i would like to make the app to save user's last location (not geo location, but the location in the app and his progress), so when the users reconnects he skips all the other screens and continues on the last screen.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks  a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Asyncstorage to save his data. It saves data on localstorage. You can then retrive his data on splash screen and get his data and navigate him.

Get started here: https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

Comment: Tnaks for your reply. I was reading about it just now. However i still do not understand how to save not jsut data but the last location in the app. Is there a specific function of adyncStorage that i should use??

Comment: You can save the route name the user was on than you can navigate him on it. Considering you are using react-navigation check this out:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/

Comment: Thanks again sir. Appreciate your help.